# Grails "Template not found error"

Tags: grails, gsp

I am getting the following error when trying to render my GSP (using Grails 2.3.6):

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Template not found for name [/shared/mymenu] and path [/shared/_mymenu.gsp]
    ...long stacktrace omitted
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Inside the `/shared/_mymenu.gsp`:

```
<g:render template="/shared/mmenustub" model="${['root':appmenu]}">
</g:render>
```

Am I missing something here? Perhaps a `plugin` attribute or something? If so, what am I missing and what should its value be?

The `globalmenu` taglib is define as follows:

```
class GlobalMenuTagLib {
    def globalmenu = { attrs, body ->
        List<NavigationScheme> allNavigationSchemes = navigationSchemeService.listAll()
        def mapped = allNavigationSchemes.groupBy { menu -> menu.appreference }
        def registeredApps = registerInfoService.listAllActive()

        def activePage = attrs.activepage
        def tempName = attrs.tempName?:'anothermenu'

        out << render(template: "/shared/$tempName", model:[navscheme: mapped, regApps: registeredApps, activepage:activePage])
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `_mymenu.gsp` template rendered?

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - there is a `grails-app/views/layouts/mylayout.gsp` file that references it: `<g:globalmenu tempName="mymenu" activepage="${grailsApplication.config.app.name}"></globalmenu>`

Comment: Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, but what is `globalmenu` tag? How is `tempMenu` attribute of that tag inferring `mymenu` to be `/shared/mymenu`? Sharing a sample app will be helpful, at least expanding the context of the question with all those details will be.

Comment: I found it @dmahapatro - its in a custom taglib that a freelancer added a while back: `render(template: "/shared/mymenu", model:[<modelHere>])`

Answer (score 2):

It is failing to find the /shared/_mymenu.gsp file. If this file exists in a plugin, then you need to reference it with the "plugin" argument in the render method so that it knows where to search for the file.

```
out << render(template: "/shared/$tempName", model:[navscheme: mapped, regApps: registeredApps, activepage:activePage], plugin: "myplugin")
```

where "myplugin" is the name of your plugin.